# Problem in DataGridView binding with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, datagridview

When i bind my linq query to the datasource of the datagridview, i cannot change any of the cells values in the gridview. The columns readonly property is automatically set to true and when i tried to set it false it gives following exception:-

DataGridView column bound to a read-only field must have ReadOnly set to True. LINQ

This is my code for it

```
 DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
 var selectquery = from s in db.Sarees where s.Bill.BillNo == billno select new { s.BillID,s.Price };
```

I found 1 solution to this problem which is not filthy if there are many columns in the table and i want to select only two...
The 1 solution is :-

```
 var selectquery = db.Sarees.Where(s => s.Bill.BillNo == billno);
```

When i gave this query it works fine..
But i want a solution in which i can select only some columns by LINQ and can change its value when binded through a datagridview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this query does not return a collection of `Sarees` so it cannot be edited like you want. It is a returning a collection of new objects with a `BillID` and a `Price` property.

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var selectquery = from s in db.Sarees
                  where s.Bill.BillNo == billno 
                  select new { s.BillID, s.Price };
```

Can you use a version of the 2nd query and bind only the columns you want to edit to the `DataGridView`?

---

You may also need to explore using the [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx).

Comment: How to use the second version and bind only some columns (eg. ID and Price) ?

Comment: That's where the CellFormatting Event comes into play. Even then, I don't know if the field changes will automatically be updated. I don't think it was intended to save objects with depth like the OP is asking.